# EXT: append data to store (datasource)

Tags: c#, extjs, ext.net

I add static data to the store:

```
List<object> data = new List<object>() {
                new { name="", grouptype="Normal Types", fieldtype="SimpleText", tooltip="", icon="../Images/buttons/01_simpletext.svg", tabular=1  }};

                LabDatatoStore();

                this.StoreControlTypes.DataSource = data;
                this.StoreControlTypes.DataBind();
```

and I am calling LabDatatoStore() to add also some dynamic data from the database:

```
protected void LabDatatoStore()
        {
            DAL.DataContext dc = new DAL.DataContext();

            var data = from i in dc.Tests
                       where i.id != "HEIGHT" && i.id != "WEIGHT"
                       select new { fieldtype = i.id, grouptype = "Data Types", tooltip = i.Name, icon = "../Images/test.png" };

            this.StoreControlTypes.DataSource = data;
            this.StoreControlTypes.DataBind();
        }
```

But I get only the static data. How I can get both ones?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved it:

```
List<object> data = new List<object>() {
                    new { name="", grouptype="Normal Types", fieldtype="SimpleText", tooltip="", icon="../Images/buttons/01_simpletext.svg" },
                    new { name="", grouptype="Normal Types", fieldtype="LongText", tooltip="", icon="../Images/buttons/02_textlong.svg"  },
                    new { name="", grouptype="Normal Types", fieldtype="Numeric", tooltip="", icon="../Images/buttons/03_numeric.svg"  }
};

DAL.DataContext dc = new DAL.DataContext();

    var dataDyn = from i in dc.Tests
        where i.id != "HEIGHT" && i.id != "WEIGHT"
        select new { fieldtype = i.id, grouptype = "Data Types", tooltip = i.Name, icon = "../Images/test.png" };


data.AddRange(dataDyn.ToArray()); 

this.StoreControlTypes.DataSource = data;
this.StoreControlTypes.DataBind();
```